# Restrict access to Logic App to Managed Identity

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure App Service that uses `HttpClient` to call a Logic App with an HTTP trigger. The App Service has a system-assigned Managed Identity. I want to restrict access to the Logic App to only this Managed Identity so that only the App Service can call the Logic App. Is that possible?

Comment: Nup, it's a bug bear of mine.  This is your only real option ... https://www.cloudshift.nl/blog/2022/10/securing-your-azure-logic-apps-with-azure-ad-oauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary: Call the logic app from the App Service passing a token instead of a shared access signature (SAS). Then, validate the token in the logic app using a policy on the subject claim.

Steps:

1. Delete the `sp`, `sv` and `sig` query parameters (this is the SAS) from the logic app URI.

```cs
// Original: "https://prod-nnn.region.logic.azure.com/workflows/877...394/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=n6R...ffo"
string logicAppUri = "https://prod-nnn.region.logic.azure.com/workflows/877...394/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01";
```

2. In the App Service code, get a token for **any** known resource and pass it to the logic app.

```cs
DefaultAzureCredential credential = new();
string anyPublicScope = "https://management.azure.com/.default";
AccessToken token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { anyPublicScope }));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new("Bearer", token.Token);

var input = new { LogicAppParam1 = 123, LogicAppParam2 = "cool" };
using StringContent content = new(JsonSerializer.Serialize(input), Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(logicAppUri, content);
```

3. Find your tenant id and the id of your App Service managed identity. In Azure portal:

- open Azure Active Directory and copy the value of `Tenant ID` from the `Overview` page.
- open your App Service, go to `Identity` and copy the value of `Object (principal) ID`.

4. In Azure portal open the logic app, go to `Authorization` and add a policy like that:

```
Policy name = Your App Service
Issuer = https://sts.windows.net/paste-tenant-id-here-and-add-a-slash/
Subject = paste-managed-identity-object-id-here
```

Add one policy for each App Service or User who must be able to trigger the logic app.

*There is NO NEED to do any of the following things, although you will find many turotials which do them:*

- *Create an App Registration for the logic app. Configure resource uri, scopes, consent options etc.*
- *Add the Audience claim to the logic app policy.*
- *Add "operationOptions": "IncludeAuthorizationHeadersInOutputs" to the logic app trigger, in code view.*
- *Parse the token with logic app actions to decide who can do what.*
- *List allowed inbound IP addresses to the logic app Workflow settings page.*

More info:

- The Issuer(`iss`) claim is required for creating a policy. You would have the same security without it (because the Subject claim is globally unique) but you just have to fill the Issuer correctly.
- The Audience(`aud`) claim contains the uri or id of the requested resource. It is deducted from the scope passed to `GetTokenAsync()`. In this case it would be `https://management.azure.com`.
  This is an arbitratry public resource, not related to the logic app, so there is no point in validating the Audience claim in the logic app policy.
  Anyone in your Azure tenant could request a token for that resource but only your specific App Service can provide a Subject claim = the id of the managed identity.
- In case you want to allow a User (not an App Service) you have two options:

  - a) Use the Subject(`sub`) claim **but** it does **not** contain the user's AAD Object ID. It contains a unique hash of the user/application combination. Decode one user token to get the claim.
  - b) (haven't tried this) The `oid` claim always contains the AAD Object ID of the User or App Service. It cannot be selected from the list in policy editor but you could `Add custom claim`.
- You cannot call a logic app with both a token and a SAS. You must remove the SAS, otherwise an error is returned. This is good - you should never store secrets in config files under version control.
- When debugging in VS, `DefaultAzureCredential` gets a token for the current user so you must add a policy for a user `sub` (see caveat above).
- When deployed to Azure, `DefaultAzureCredential` gets a token for the managed identity of the App Service.
- There are shorter methods to send JSON with `HttpClient` like `.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, input)` and `.PostAsync(uri, JsonContent.Create(input))`
  **but** after I added the `Authorization` header they stopped working - they sent an empty body. This is why I use the longer `StringContent` variant but you might be luckier.

Example policies for 2 App Services and 1 User:
[image: Logic app authorization policies]

Comment: Fantastic answer. There is just one thing I don't quite understand. Why can I get a token for `https://management.azure.com/.default` even if I haven't explicitly given permission for the Managed Identity to access this resource?

Answer (score 0):

Using Authorization parameter, you can restrict access to logic app with managed identity.

Have an azure webapp which is used to call logic app with Http client.

I have created logic app by taking **HTTP tigger** as shown below ,
[image]

**In HTTP trigger**, added **Authorization** parameter as shown below,
[image]

Selected authentication type as **Managed Identity**,
[image]
[image]
You can also restrict accessing logic app by adding app service IP range in logic app workflow settings
Logic app>>Workflow Settings
[image]
In this way, logic app can be accessible only from configured Ip addresses.
Reference [link](https://medium.com/@sumindaniro/secure-azure-logic-apps-and-function-apps-using-api-management-with-oauth-2-0-client-credent-77b1176be243#:%7E:text=Restrict%20Direct%20Access%20to%20Logic%20App%20Go%20to,as%20below.%20Restrict%20Direct%20Access%20to%20Function%20App)

Comment: Your screenshots show an HTTP action and not the HTTP trigger.

Comment: @Mo B. Kindly note that, any logic app will start with only a trigger not with an action. Provided screen shot contains a HTTP trigger. It is not a HTTP action.

Comment: @Mo B. kindly check edited answer. For your clarification Added the http trigger reference screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your answer is wrong. You are using an HTTP *recurrence* trigger which periodically *sends* requests rather than receives them. I want to secure a logic app that is triggered by an HTTP request. That's a different trigger.